# android - file.exists() returns false for existing file (for anything different than pdf)

Tags: android, file

Both files are present on the sdcard, but for whatever reason `exists()` returns false for the png file.

```
// String path = "/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.gemoro.toffer/cache/1551619351/0/foto/-921042926.png";
  String path = "/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.gemoro.toffer/cache/1551619351/0/foto/-1200240592.pdf";
            
File file2 = new File(path);
    
if (null != file2) {
    if (file2.exists()) {
        LOG.x("file exists");
    } else {
        LOG.x("file does not exist");
    }
}
```

Now, I've looked at what's under the hood and what the expression `file.exists()` actually does, and this is what it does:

```
public boolean exists() {
    return doAccess(F_OK);
}
    
private boolean doAccess(int mode) {
    try {
        return Libcore.os.access(path, mode);
    } catch (ErrnoException errnoException) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

May it be that the method finishes by throwing the exception and returning false?

If so,

- how can I make this work?
- what other options to check if a file exists on the sdcard are available for use?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you (Java) don't have the permissions to access both files?

Comment: I think I do:     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1 You need get the permission of device

Add this to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

2 Get the external storage directory

```
File sdDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

3 At last, check the file

```
File file = new File(sdDir + filename /* what you want to load in SD card */);
if (!file.canRead()) {
    return false;
}
return true;
```

**Note: filename is the path in the sdcard, not in root.**

For example: you want find

```
/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.gemoro.toffer/cache/1551619351/0/foto/-921042926.png
```

then filename is

```
./Android/data/com.gemoro.toffer/cache/1551619351/0/foto/-921042926.png
```

.

Comment: Can you help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36870191/why-does-my-file-not-exist-even-when-i-gave-it-a-path-that-exist/36871937?noredirect=1#comment61310822_36871937

Comment: use  return folder.canRead(); instead of if conditiion

Answer (score 3):

Please try this code. Hope it should helpful for you. I am using this code only. Its working fine for me to find the file is exists or not. Please try and let me know.

```
File file = new File(path);
    if (!file.isFile()) {
         Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :" + filePath);
    }else{
    Log.e("uploadFile","file exist");
}
```

Comment: i'm running tests on an old android device (Samsung GT-i5510 and Android 2.3.6) and was getting crazy because file.exists() was returning false. Your answer solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Check that USB Storage is not connected to the PC. Since Android device is connected to the PC as storage the files are not available for the application and you get FALSE to File.Exists().

Answer (score 3):

Check file exist in internal storage

Example : /storage/emulated/0/FOLDER_NAME/FILE_NAME.EXTENTION

1. check permission (write storage)
2. and check file exist or not

   `public static boolean isFilePresent(String fileName) {
       return getFilePath(fileName).isFile();
   }`
3. get File from the file name

   `public static File getFilePath(String fileName){
       String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
       File folder = new File(extStorageDirectory, "FOLDER_NAME");
       File filePath = new File(folder + "/" + fileName);
       return filePath;
   }`