# Why does my file not exist even when I gave it a path that exist?

Tags: android

My if condition on `imgFile.exist()` is giving me false, but I can see the file exist in the path when Log.d prints its result out.

I'm simply trying to load an image from a path to put it as a background of an activitys miniature image

I also have the read/write permission in my manifest `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

**LOADING A IMAGE:**

```
File imgFile = new  File(getRowItem.getImgURI().trim());
Log.d("TAGG", "FILE PATH: " + imgFile.getPath());
// imgFile's path: /storage/emulated/0/TravelDiary/img_1461684314337.jpg


if(imgFile.exists()){

    //it never reach inside here

    Log.d("TAGG", "FILE ABSOLUTE PATH: " + imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
    Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), myBitmap);
    imageView.setBackground(drawable);
}
```

**SAVING A IMAGE:**

*a image is saved when the user from a intentChooser chooses to caputure a image from either the camera or choosing the image from gallary*

```
 public void ImagePicker(View v){

if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
        if (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,  Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) && PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED  == ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,  Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

            final File rootdir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "TravelDiary");
            rootdir.mkdirs();
            final String filename = "img_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
            final File sdImageMainDirecotry = new File(rootdir, filename);
            outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirecotry);
            ...
            ...


     } else {
            //if permission is not granted, then we ask for it
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,  Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
       }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "External storage not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**Permissions in my Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.muddii.traveldiary">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

 ...
 ...
 ...

</manifest>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android - file.exists() returns false for existing file (for anything different than pdf)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21579468/android-file-exists-returns-false-for-existing-file-for-anything-different)

Comment: Perhaps you have not requested `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` or `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` as a permission. If you have, perhaps [there is a problem in how you are doing that](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/08/31/hey-where-did-my-permission-go.html).

Comment: @CommonsWare I have done that before I asked the question. Thats not where the problem is I think

Comment: @pablisco non of these solutions in the link has helped.

Comment: @CommonsWare  I have edited my question to show how I save a image before I load it

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: AAnd READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, do you have it too?

Comment: @RicardoBarroca yes.

Comment: check the second line.

Comment: @josedlujan I have them both

Comment: @josedlujan I have edited my question to show how I save a image before I load it

Answer (score 0):

What is your SDK value in gradle? If it is 23 then you need to ask for permission at run time.

http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Its 23 and I have the permission is requested when the user clicks on a Icon which then shows a intentChooser where the user can either pick a image from gallery or take one from camera

Comment: If you have not requested RUNTIME permission and are running on a marshmallow device, you will not have access to external storage regardless of what permissions are specified in your manifest.

Comment: I have that.  Look at my edited question where I shows it

Comment: I also tested the app on Samsung Galaxy S5 which dosn't require permission as in Android 6.0 without any succses. So I dont think it lies with permissions

Answer (score 0):

try this instead of imgFile.exists()

```
File file = new File(path);
if (!file.isFile()) {
    //your code
}else{
//your code
}
```