# Android file exists() not working

Tags: java, android

Right now I'm currently trying to make a file downloaded from a `Uri`, but I wanna make it so that if the file has been downloaded it's wont be able to download it anymore. So i decided to use `file.exists()` to do that, But right now the `file.exists()` method isn't working for some reason.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://kmmc.in/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/lesson2.pdf");

Uri path = Uri.parse("file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/");
String test = uri.getPath();
File file = new File(path.getPath());
File check = new File(path.getPath()+uri.getLastPathSegment());
if (!check.exists()||!check.isFile()) {
  DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
  request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
  request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(String.valueOf(file), uri.getLastPathSegment());
  Long reference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
}
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ViewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("book",""+uri.getLastPathSegment()+"");
startActivity(intent);
```

I try to do a file check and see if file exist or not, but I always get file doesn't exist even though the file is already downloaded and on the right place. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: `isFile` will return false itself if it doesn't exist

Comment: @cricket_007 I misunderstood the question...deleted my answer

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21579468/android-file-exists-returns-false-for-existing-file-for-anything-different ?

Comment: @alexander.egger Tried folowing that one and still doesn't work

Comment: Aside from the `exists()` question, your approach is silly. The fact that file 'x.foo' exists does NOT mean I downloaded it, nor I downloaded it completely nor I downloaded it correctly. It just means there's file with that name and this is completely different thing and you cannot draw any conclusion from that fact about file origin or content.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Sorry if it's like that but do you have any other approach you'd like to tell me? Please do tell

Comment: do NOT prevent re-download. If user wants to, let him do that. You may restrict the IP or say IP class x.x.x.* but do not block the feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Instead of :**

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(String.valueOf(file), uri.getLastPathSegment());
```

**Use:**

```
 request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, uri
                    .getLastPathSegment());
```

**Reason:**

`setDestinationInExternalPublicDir` is expecting `dirType` as your first parameter:

But when set it to `String.valueOf(file)` it will store the file in `/storage/emulated/0/storage/emulated/0/Download/lesson2.pdf` instead of `storage/emulated/0/Download/`. As a result your condition always fails.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

`if (!check.exists()||!check.isFile())` - is not good, as, in theory, it may trigger on a folder that has a name lessons2.pdf. So, `isFile()` alone should suffice.

Make sure you have all the permissions in Manifest

android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

and that you have asked for read/write permissions runtime, too.

and access the downloads folder through

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString();
```

because it may be emulated/0/Downloads or it maybe different, depending on whether the phone is used in a guest mode.

and name

```
String name = Uri.parse("http://kmmc.in/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/lesson2.pdf").getLastPathSegment();`
```

then do your check with

```
File check = new File(path, name);
```

Comment: Tried it and it's still downloading even if the file exists